# How to add a condition for an array on an entity query for a config entity?

Tags: 8

I want to execute an entity query on a config entity type. However when I want to add an `IN` condition on a property which is an array I am getting an error.

For example, I want to retrieve all user roles that have the `administer nodes` permission:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user_role')->getQuery();
$query->condition('permissions', ['administer nodes'], 'IN');
$query->execute();
```

This gives the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  mb_strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/Entity/Query/Condition.php on line 166
```

Answer (score 1):

A config entity doesn't use a normalized table structure, so the normal array conditions which use JOIN don't work. Instead do a condition on `property.*`:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user_role')->getQuery();
$query->condition('permissions.*', 'administer nodes');
$query->execute();
```